# Getting a cmdlet's dynamic parameters via reflection

Tags: reflection, powershell, system.reflection, powershell-cmdlet

Powershell exposes some parameters, "[dynamic parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878334%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)", based on context. The MSDN page explains the mechanism pretty well, but the skinny is that to find out about these one must call [GetDynamicParameters()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.idynamicparameters.getdynamicparameters%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which returns a class containing the additional parameters. I need to get these parameters via reflection, and (here's the crux of it), in a ReflectionOnly context (that is, the types are loaded with ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom). So, no Assembly.InvokeMember("GetDynamicParameters").

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Reflection works against static assembly metadata. Dynamic parameters in powershell are added at *runtime* by the command or function itself.

Comment: This is my understanding as well :(. I am just hoping that somebody is aware of a clever solution I just hadn't thought of.

Comment: There are no clever solutions; only annoying, difficult ones. Dynamic parameters may be implemented as a simple class with properties, or as a RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary. You'd have to guess at the former classes and reflect on them, and for the latter, you'd have to run the actual code to build the dictionary. So, the answer is still no. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps:

1: Defintion of the dynamic parameters

```
#===================================================================================
# DEFINITION OF FREE FIELDS USED BY THE CUSTOMER
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# SYNTAX: @{ <FF-Name>=@(<FF-Number>,<isMandatory_CREATE>,<isMandatory_UPDATE>); }
$usedFFs = @{               
                      "defaultSMTP"=@(2,1,0); `
                      "allowedSMTP"=@(3,1,0); `
                       "secondName"=@(100,1,0); `
                            "orgID"=@(30001,1,0); `
            "allowedSubjectTypeIDs"=@(30002,1,0); `
            }

# FF-HelpMessage for input          
$usedFFs_HelpMSG = @{ 2="the default smtp domain used by the organizaiton. Sampel:'algacom.ch'"; `
                      3="comma seperated list of allowed smtp domains. Sampel:'algacom.ch,basel.algacom.ch'"; `
                      100="an additional organization name. Sampel:'algaCom AG')"; `
                      30001="an unique ID (integer) identifying the organization entry"; `
                      30002="comma seperated list of allowed subject types. Sampel:'1,2,1003,10040'"; `
            }
```

2: definition of function that builds the dynamic parameters

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
# Build-DynParams : Used to build the dynamic input parameters based on $usedFFs / $usedFFs_HelpMSG
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function Build-DynParams($type) {
    $paramDictionary = New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

    foreach($ffName in $usedFFs.Keys) {
        $ffID = $usedFFs.Item($ffName)[0]
        $dynAttribCol = New-Object -Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $dynAttrib = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $dynAttrib.ParameterSetName = "__AllParameterSets"
        $dynAttrib.HelpMessage = $usedFFs_HelpMSG.Item($ffID)
        switch($type) {
            "CREATE" { $dynAttrib.Mandatory = [bool]($usedFFs.Item($ffName)[1]) }
            "UPDATE" { $dynAttrib.Mandatory = [bool]($usedFFs.Item($ffName)[2]) }
        }   
        $dynAttribCol.Add($dynAttrib)   
        $dynParam = New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ffName, [string], $dynAttribCol)
        $paramDictionary.Add($ffName, $dynParam)        
    }
    return $paramDictionary         
}
```

3. Function that makes use of the dynamic params

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# aAPS-OrganizationAdd : This will add a new organization entry
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function aAPS-OrganizationAdd {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="The name of the new organization")] 
        [String]$Descr,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,HelpMessage="The name of the parent organization")] 
        [String]$ParentDescr=$null,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,HelpMessage="The status of the new organization [1=Active|2=Inactive]")] 
        [int]$Status = 1,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,HelpMessage="If you want to see the data of the deactivated object")] 
        [switch]$ShowResult
    )
    DynamicParam { Build-DynParams "CREATE" }

    Begin {}

    Process {
        # do what oyu want here
    }

    End {}
}
```